# How to have about dialog in e4 with eclipse neon?

Tags: e4, eclipse-neon

I am wondering is there any way I can have an about dialog like it was in eclipse 3.x.I remember it was not supported in e4 but with release of neon whether about dialog is migrated to e4.Any help on this will be appreciated..

Comment: What part of the about dialog are you asking about? Doing a simple About dialog has always been doable in e4.

Comment: @greg I  want to fetch the installation details

Comment: There is no change in that. e4 does not provide dialogs like that so it is not likely ever to be provided as standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no change in the status of the About dialog in e4 for Eclipse Neon.

You can code a simple about dialog yourself which should be invoked from a handler for the `org.eclipse.ui.help.aboutAction` command (required to make About work properly on macOS).

It is not likely that support for things like the Installation Details will ever be added to core e4. Not least because this requires the p2 install code which is optional for an e4 RCP.

Comment: Is there a way to get the information on "Installation Details" dialog -> "Configuration" tab contents in e4?

Comment: @JehanZeb The classes that build that information are not included in e4. But some of the information should be available through various APis that can be used in e4